# How do I change the console output language in Sphinx>=4.0 when using VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-sphinx

I'm looking for a way to change Sphinx's console output language. After upgrading from 3.5.4 to 4.0.2, I noticed that the console output that's displayed when the documentation is building, is displayed in my native language, instead of in English like it was before. I'd prefer the English output language back. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Does adding `language = "en"` to your `conf.py` work? See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-internationalization

Comment: Nope. Although I noticed that running Sphinx from outside of VSCode makes everything display in english, like it used to do so before - it's only when I build my documentation from inside VSCode, is where it uses my native language.

Comment: Do you use the same virtual environment and source files both inside and outside VSCode?

Comment: Yes, I do. I don't use a virtual env, source files are the same. My project: https://github.com/DevilXD/aRez

The Shpinx requirement is not updated yet, cos I was reporting an issue: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9273

If you clone the repo@dev and open my project in VSCode, you should be able to F1 -> Select Tasks -> Build Documentation (which literally just runs `make html` from the docs folder). Make sure to `pip install -U sphinx` to get the latest 4.0.2 version first, cos it wasn't happening on the previous one I had.

Comment: This makes it use my native language when I run it from VSCode, but English language when I run it from outside, via just `make html` in the `cmd` in the docs folder.

Comment: Because you do not use a Python virtual environment, there is no way I can replicate what you see. I never install Python packages into my system, and only a very select few packages into my user space. I always prefer virtual environments.